# css resize div based on scroll position

Tags: css

I know how to do this is JavaScript but is it possible to-do using css and media queries only to achieve the same result.

If the the window scroll position is greater than 100 
then resize "myDiv" height to 100px
and if window scroll position is less than 100px
then resize "myDiv" height to its default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do this with CSS, if you want to manipulate the view based on the current viewport position/scroll bar you need JavaScript.